# Is Amazon SNS ideal for Comet solution?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, comet, amazon-sns

Is [Amazon SNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services#List_of_AWS_services) an ideal solution for a notification system like Facebook's web page notifications when a web application is written in PHP?

By ideal I mean performance and scalability in terms of price.

Comment: What are Facebook web page notifications?

Comment: the icon in the left side of messages

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not -- as SNS messages cannot be sent to individual clients as AJAX/Comet requests. SNS (Simple Notification System) is mostly geared toward server management and grid-processing systems.